# $\|S(t)\| \leq Me^{ct} \Rightarrow \|u\|_{C(0,T,H)} \leq \|u_0\|_H+\|f\|_{L^1(0,T,H)}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, semigroup-of-operators, cauchy-problem

Let $A$ be the infinitesimal generator of a $C_0$-semigroup of contractions $(S(t))$ in a Hilbert space $H$ and $f\in L^1(0,T;H)$. We know that the mild solution of the problem
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
u_t=Au+f,\\
u(0)=u_0 \in H,
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
is given by
$$u(t)=S(t)u_0+\int_{0}^{t}S(t-s)f(s)ds.\tag{*}$$
Then, since $\|S(t)\|_{\mathcal{L}(H)}\leq 1$ for all $t \geq 0$ it follows that
$$\|u\|_{C(0,T,H)} \leq \|u_0\|_H+\|f\|_{L^1(0,T,H)} \tag{**}.$$

**My question:** Does the inequality $(**)$ holds with the assumption $\|S(t)\| \leq Me^{ct}$ for all $t \geq 0$, with $M,c>0$?

From $(*)$ we have that:
$$\|u\|_{C(0,T,H)} \leq Me^{cT}(\|u_0\|_{H}+\|f\|_{L^1(0,T,H)}).$$

Is there any way to remove the term $Me^{cT}$ from the last inequality?

Comment: Is there a sign error between the Cauchy problem and the mild formulation of the solution (e.g. in the sign of $Au$)?

Comment: @RhysSteele Thank you! I fixed the problem.

Comment: Please don't use titles that are entirely MathJax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see that this bound is the best that you can get in the general setting, consider the case $H = \mathbb{R}$ and $S(t)x = e^t \cdot x$. Then $Ax = x$ and the equation in question is $$u_t - u = f.$$
To see an example where equality is achieved in your bound, consider $f = 0$ and $u_0 = 1$. Then one has $u(t) = e^{t}$.